# Efficient multicolor search

Tags: image-processing, dynamic, color, nearest, computer-vision

I'm hoping someone can help me improve the following fun code-snippet, which takes a target color and searches through a set of images to find the ones that most closely match:

```
data = ResourceData["CIFAR-10", "TestData"][[;; ;; 100, 1]];
cols = DominantColors[#, 10, {"Color", "Coverage"}] & /@ data;
ColorSlider[Dynamic[targetColor]]
Dynamic[distances = Table[Min[(Function[c, ColorDistance[c, targetColor]] /@ cc[[All, 1]])*(1/cc[[All, 2]])], {cc, cols}];
 Magnify@Row@data[[Ordering[distances, 5]]]
 ]
```

[image]

Ok, so it basically works. But here are the two things missing:

**Problem 1.**  I’m hoping someone can help make it more efficient so it can scale a little better, the example runs on only 100 images. I would like to replace the brute-force `Table` with a call to `Nearest` - but I'm not quite sure how.

**Problem 2.**  I'd also like to search based on multiple colors (2 or more weighted colors), but have not had much success. Here's the naive approach of adding the distances:

```
Column@{ColorSlider[Dynamic[targetColor1]], ColorSlider[Dynamic[targetColor2]]}
        Dynamic[distances = Table[Min[(Function[c, ColorDistance[c, targetColor1]] /@ cc[[All, 1]])*(1/cc[[All, 2]]) + (Function[c, ColorDistance[c, targetColor2]] /@ cc[[All, 1]])*(1/cc[[All, 2]])], {cc, cols}]; Magnify@Row@data[[Ordering[distances, 10]]]]
```

[image]

This doesn't work very well, I'm thinking of perhaps tweaking the distance function and using the LAB colorspace.

**References & Links:**

Helpful examples and related articles:

- https://www.fastcompany.com/90166015/this-new-google-tool-is-like-reverse-image-search-for-color-palettes
- https://github.com/spotify/annoy
- https://labs.tineye.com/color/
- http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.26.2916&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Some sort of dimension reduction sounds like it could be useful here.

Comment: A list of color coordinates with weights doesn’t seem super high dimensional though right?

Comment: Your example with two query colors actually isn’t that bad

Comment: So it's not super terrible, the but colors sort of average out and most importantly - the lookup is totally inefficient!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative approach might be to use the built-in ImageDistance function.

```
data = ResourceData["CIFAR-10", "TestData"][[;; ;; 100, 1]];
ColorSlider[Dynamic[targetColor]]
Dynamic[dist = ImageDistance[Image[targetColor], #] & /@ data;
        Magnify@Row@data[[Ordering[dist, 5]]]]
```

Of course you can choose any of the possible DistanceFunctions. This can be sped up significantly by using a NearestFunction to calculate the ImageDistance between the target and the collection of images. For example:

```
data = ResourceData["CIFAR-10", "TestData"][[;; ;; 100, 1]];
nf = Nearest[data];
ColorSlider[Dynamic[targetColor]]
Dynamic[nf[Image[targetColor], 5]]
```

To address the issue of a multiple color selector, this can be incorporated smoothly by setting the "targetColor" image to have two different colors. Now the ImageDistance will react to both the chosen colors.

```
data = ResourceData["CIFAR-10", "TestData"][[;; ;; 100, 1]];
nf = Nearest[data];
{ColorSlider[Dynamic[targetColor1]], ColorSlider[Dynamic[targetColor2]]}
 Dynamic[targetColorAll = 
   ImageAssemble[{Image[targetColor1], Image[targetColor2]}]]
 Dynamic[nf[Image[targetColorAll], 5]]
```

Comment: Earth mover is notoriously slow and won’t scale

Comment: None of them are fast

Comment: The only way to scale it is to compute color features and index them into a approximate nearest neighbors forrest

Comment: Also this doesn’t address multicolor search

Comment: See updates, which address both your issues, still within the framework of using ImageDistance.

Comment: I’ll give you the award, but if you ever have time to update it to use nmslib or neural nets that would be awesome!

Comment: So that it works like something in those links on 100k full size images...

Comment: Thanks -- it's an interesting problem. Though it's going to be pretty hard to compete with Google -- they have computational resources that no PC will ever match.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a `NearestFunction` that will do what you did with `Table`:

```
nf = Nearest[
  Hold /@ cols -> "Index", (* Hold seems to be necessary to make sure Nearest doesn't get confused by the inner lists *)
  DistanceFunction -> Function[
    Min @ Divide[
      Map[
       Function[col,
        ColorDistance[#1, col]
        ],
       #2[[1, All, 1]]
       ],
      #2[[1, All, 2]]
      ]
    ]
  ];
```

I also recommend that you use the `TrackedSymbols -> {targetColor}` option in your `Dynamic` to make sure it only updates whenever `targetColor` changes.